# Does disabling viewstate in a page do anything if it has a masterpage with it enabled?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a page that uses a master page.

I disabled viewstate on the page (not the master page), and I didn't notice that the viewstate was reduced.

Curious if the masterpage setting will override it?

Comment: did you set EnableViewState="False" or ViewStateMode="Disabled"

Answer (score 0):

In my testing setting `EnabledViewState = "False"` will not reduce the page's view state while setting `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` will decrease the viewstate size

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewStateTest.master.cs" Inherits="Sample.ViewStateTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Child Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ViewStateTest.master"         AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewstateTestPage.aspx.cs"         Inherits="Sample.ViewstateTestPage" ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```